# Initialising a pl/sql record type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

In PL/SQL, a `varray` can be initialised at creation time as:

```
TYPE colour_tab IS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(20);
    french_colours colour_tab := colour_tab('RED','WHITE','BLUE');
```

Is there an equivalent method of initialisation for PL/SQL record types?

```
type location_record_type is record (
      street_address       varchar2(40),
     postal_code          varchar2(12),
      city                 varchar2(30),
     state_province       varchar2(25),
     country_id           char(2) not null := 'US'
    );
```

Comment: If you make that type as database object then you can do that. Or I think you must if you don't create a constructor function to the object type.

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28208606/214728, this should work similar to the colour_tab := colour_tab('RED','WHITE','BLUE') codings

Comment: Oracle 18c introduces the ability you are looking for - see my answer below for more detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not. You have to assign each value explicitly. [Documentation reference here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#sthref1191).

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28208606/214728, this should work similar to the colour_tab := colour_tab('RED','WHITE','BLUE') codings

Answer (score 9):

Use a function to act as a kind of "constructor" function (look at function f()):

```
DECLARE
  TYPE ty_emp IS RECORD(
    id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR(30),
    deptcode VARCHAR(10)
    );
  TYPE ty_tbl_emp IS TABLE OF ty_emp;
  tbl_emp ty_tbl_emp;
  FUNCTION f (             -- <==============
    id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR,
    deptcode VARCHAR) RETURN ty_emp IS
  e ty_emp;
  BEGIN
    e.id := id;
    e.name := name;
    e.deptcode := deptcode;
    RETURN e;
  END f;
BEGIN

  tbl_emp := ty_tbl_emp(
    f(1, 'Johnson', 'SALES'), 
    f(2, 'Peterson', 'ADMIN'));
  Dbms_Output.put_line(tbl_emp(2).name);
END;
```

Answer (score 5):

Oracle 18c allows record initialization with [qualified expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-4B379569-4068-4DB1-9D69-E706F4AC5758):

```
declare 
type location_record_type is record (
      street_address       varchar2(40),
     postal_code          varchar2(12),
      city                 varchar2(30),
     state_province       varchar2(25),
     country_id           char(2) not null := 'US'
    );

myvar location_record_type;
myvar2 location_record_type := location_record_type(street_address => 'my street'
                                                   ,postal_code    => 'my code'
                                                   ,city           => 'my city'
                                                   ,state_province => 'my state'
                                                   ,country_id     => 'GB'
                                                   );

begin
  dbms_output.put_line(myvar.country_id);
  dbms_output.put_line(myvar2.city);
end;
/
```

Output of the above is ...

```
US
my city
```

You can run the above sample code in Oracle Live SQL [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/gcb3ykf4xsjg2ijw8oakkwsoc).  (Unfortunately that site requires a logon.)

Answer (score 3):

Record types are really designed for holding rows from SELECT statements.

```
    ....
    type location_record_type is record (
          street_address       varchar2(40),
         postal_code          varchar2(12),
          city                 varchar2(30),
         state_province       varchar2(25),
         country_id           char(2) not null := 'US'
        );
    type location_record_nt is table of location_record_type;
    loc_recs location_record_nt;
begin
    select street_name
           , pcode
           , city
           , region
           , country_code
    bulk collect into loc_recs
    from t69
    where ....
```

Obviously for cases where the query isn't a SELECT * FROM a single table (because in that scenario we can use `%ROWTYPE` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Record initialization is performed in its declaration 
and record assignment by selecting into from DUAL:

```
    declare
        type location_record_type is record
        (
            street_address       varchar2(40) := '1234 Fake Street',
            postal_code          varchar2(12) := '90210',
            city                 varchar2(30) := 'Springfield',
            state_province       varchar2(25) := 'KY',
            country_id           char(2) not null := 'US'
        );
        v_location location_record_type;

   begin 
      select 
        '4321 Another St.', '48288', 'Detroit', 'MI', v_location.country_id
      into v_location from dual;
    end;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that return that record type.

See below sample code:

```
DECLARE
   type location_record_type is record (
      street_address       varchar2(40),
      postal_code          varchar2(12),
      city                 varchar2(30),
      state_province       varchar2(25),
      country_id           char(2) not null := 'US');
   v_loc_rec location_record_type;
   FUNCTION new_loc_rec RETURN location_record_type
   IS
      v_new_loc_rec location_record_type;
   BEGIN
      return v_new_loc_rec;
   END;
BEGIN
    v_loc_rec := new_loc_rec;
    v_loc_rec.state_province := 'SomeState';
    v_loc_rec.country_id := 'SU';
    dbms_output.put_line('State: '||v_loc_rec.state_province||'; Country_ID: '||v_loc_rec.country_id);
    v_loc_rec := new_loc_rec;
    dbms_output.put_line('State: '||v_loc_rec.state_province||'; Country_ID: '||v_loc_rec.country_id);
END;
```